# Unable to save data from multiline textbox to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, multiline

I am trying to save multiline textbox data to a table in a SQL Server database, however, I get an error "Invalid Column Name".

**Background**

I have multiline text boxes on a form, the user will enter his/her name in 2 different languages (viz., English & Arabic). First-line in Arabic and second-line English. In the next textbox, the user mentions quantity.

Along with this info, there are other several fields that go along. So far I have tried the below code.

```
ValidateField(textBox47);

if (HasEmptyField)
{
    return;
}

query = "insert into tbl_overall_details (Serial_no, Batch_no, Worder_no, Worder_date, Service_no, Blue_name, Blue_name_qty) VALUES (@d1, @d2, @d3, @d4,@d5, @d6,@d7)";

cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query);
cmd1.Connection = con;

cmd1.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lbl_serail_no.Text.Trim();
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lbl_batch_no.Text.Trim();
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@d3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text.Trim();
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@d4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateTimePicker1.Text.Trim();
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@d5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text.Trim();
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@d6", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox45.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"\r\n").Trim();
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@d7", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox47.Text;

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Table:
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_nametally_details](    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  [Serial_no] [int] NOT NULL,     [Batch_no] [int] NOT NULL,  [Worder_no] [int] NOT NULL,     [Worder_date] [date] NOT NULL,  [Service_no] [int] NOT NULL,    [Blue_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    [Blue_name_qty] [int] NULL,     [DPM_name_qty] [int] NULL,  CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_nametally_details] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`

The column in the table has data type `NVarChar(50)`, there is no spelling mistakes in code.

Please advice.

Comment: Please attach the relevant DB table schema to the question. Thanks.

Comment: One possible reason could be you are trying to pass a longer string than column size in your database. Do you have any data validation in your front end validating length of this field that it is not more than 50?

Comment: There is no validation in the front end to check the length of the user input, I have tried passing names of different length and less then 50 characters.

Comment: The create table command is creating a table named `tbl_nametally_details` … the query is using a table named… `tbl_overall_details` … this looks like two (2) different tables? You should [edit] your question and add the code to your question and not as a comment.

Comment: @JohnG you are right, it was pure my foolishness that I did not check table name into which I am trying to save the data. Its done and resolved. Thank you.